# scanf inside a loop in C

Tags: c

I want to make the user enter a date (3 numbers), but if he enters any letter he has to re-enter the date, I have this code but it doesn't work, what should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsfF0.png)

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read a line of input. Use `sscanf()` to parse it, and check the return value to see if all 3 numbers parsed correctly.

Comment: increase `res` variable by `res++`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @YAN `res` is to check that all three fields were correctly scanned. It's not some kind of time-out attempts.